# Algorithm design manual (Steven Skiena) regarding random samples on Ordered pairs Page 250

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, random

given the following explanation

> Problem: We need an efficient and unbiased way to generate random
>   pairs of vertices to perform random vertex swaps. Propose an efficient
>   algorithm to generate elements from the (n 2) unordered pairs on {1,
>   . . . , n} uniformly at random.
>
> Solution: Uniformly generating random structures is a surprisingly
>   subtle problem. Consider the following procedure to generate random
>   unordered pairs: i = random int(1,n-1); j = random int(i+1,n);
>
> It is clear that this indeed generates unordered pairs, since i < j.
>   Further, it is clear that all (n 2) unordered pairs can indeed be
>   generated, assuming that random int generates integers uniformly
>   between its two arguments.
>
> But are they uniform? The answer is no. What is the probability that
>   pair (1,2) is generated? There is a 1/(n−1) chance of getting the 1,
>   and then a 1/(n−1) chance of getting the 2, which yields p(1,2) = 1/(n
>   − 1)2. But what is the probability of getting (n − 1,n)? Again, there
>   is a 1/n chance of getting the first number, but now there is only one
>   possible choice for the second candidate! This pair will occur n times
>   more often than the first! The problem is that fewer pairs start with
>   big numbers than little numbers. We could solve this problem by
>   calculating exactly how unordered pairs start with i (exactly (n − i))
>   and appropriately bias the probability. The second value could then be
>   selected uniformly at random from i + 1 to n.
>   But instead of working through the math, let’s exploit the fact that
>   randomly generating the n2 ordered pairs uniformly is easy. Just pick
>   two integers independently of each other. Ignoring the ordering (i.e.
>   , permuting the ordered pair to unordered pair (x,y) so that x < y)
>   gives us a 2/n^2 probability of generating each unordered pair of
>   distinct elements. If we happen to generate a pair (x,x), we discard
>   it and try again. We will get unordered pairs uniformly at random in
>   constant expected time using the following algorithm:

1. in the above paragraph "The problem is that fewer pairs start with
   big numbers than little numbers." shouldn't this be  more pairs  instead of fewer pairs
2. in the above paragraph "We could solve this problem by calculating exactly how unordered pairs start with i (exactly (n − i))" shouldn't this me how many unordered pairs rather than how unordered pairs

**EDIT**

3. in the above paragraph "Ignoring the ordering (i.e.
   , permuting the ordered pair to unordered pair (x,y) so that x < y)
   gives us a 2/n^2 probability of generating each unordered pair of
   distinct elements." how is the probability 2/n^2 derived ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [the errata](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/algorist/book/errata)?

Comment: i did but apparently i had a old version of it.So thanks for the link.Still there errata that you have provided does not explain question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the above paragraph "The problem is that fewer pairs start with big numbers than little numbers." shouldn't this be more pairs instead of fewer pairs

No, it's fewer.:

```
n - 1 pairs start with 1 (1 2; 1 3; ...; 1 n)
n - 2 pairs start with 2 (2 3; 2 4; ...; 2 n)
n - 3 pairs start with 3
...
```

> in the above paragraph "We could solve this problem by calculating exactly how unordered pairs start with i (exactly (n − i))" shouldn't this me how many unordered pairs rather than how unordered pairs

Yes, there is a missing "many" there.

> in the above paragraph "Ignoring the ordering (i.e. , permuting the ordered pair to unordered pair (x,y) so that x < y) gives us a 2/n^2 probability of generating each unordered pair of distinct elements." how is the probability 2/n^2 derived ?

There are `n*n` possibilities of generating pairs where order does matter (`1 2` and `2 1` are different pairs). Since you then proceed to ignore the ordering, both `1 2` and `2 1` will be the same, so you have two favorable cases.

This does not account for the fact that you discard `x x` pairs though. Then it would be `2 / (n*(n - 1))`, because if you pick `x` once, you only have `n - 1` possibilities for the second pick.

Comment: thank for the explanation.would you mind explaining what is the effect of this have on the result of i j pair not being uniform? does this mean that if the pairs start with big numbers have a higher chance of repeating

Comment: @user119020 Yes, this is biased towards "larger" pairs.

Comment: thanks again. but i still cant wrap my head around it. i can undestand that there is a high chance of  the same pair being repeated if the pair start with a big number.But there is no bias of the 1st number being a big number right.So  lets say if this is run 10 times so isn't there equal probability of the 1st number being small number as well as a big number? thus wouldn't you get uniformly spread result?

Comment: @user119020 let's say we want to generate random unordered pairs of `n` numbers for `n = 4`. These would be `1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 2 3; 2 4; 3 4`. Notice that three of them start with `1`, two of them start with `2` and a single one starts with `3`. You are correct that there is no bias for the first number, and that is exactly the problem. There should be a bias: `3` should appear fewer times than `1`. But it won't, so `3 4` will appear more times than it should. You should bias the first random number generator towards picking smaller numbers more often.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indices for your n items are 0..(n-1), and `random(n)` gives a random number ≥ 0 and < n :

```
i = random(n)
j = random(n-1)
j = (i+j+1) % n
```

Now every pair (i,j) with i≠j has exactly probability 1/(n(n-1)). Obviously, swapping (i,j) has the same result as swapping (j,i).

You could also do:

```
i = random(n)
j = random(n)
```

And ignore the fact that this may result in (i,i) pairs (swapping them will have no effect).